# How do I find and list compositions for (f) and (g)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, functional-equations, function-and-relation-composition

Ok, I've literally just spent the last 2 hours just to figure out two compositions problems for homework, and I've about had it. Anyone here that can help?

**Problem 1**
$$ f(x) = 2x(2) - x -3 $$ 
$$ g(x) = x + 1 $$ 
Find:
$$ f + g $$ 
$$ f - g $$ 
$$ f\cdot g $$ 
$$ \frac{f}{g} $$ 
$$ (f \circ g)(2) $$

**Problem 2**
$$ f(x) = 2x - 3 $$
$$ g(x) = \frac{x+3}{6} $$ 
Find: 
$$ (f\circ g)(x) $$ 
$$ (g\circ f)(x) $$
$$ (f\circ g)(2) $$
$$ (F\circ g)(6) $$

Comment: By $f*g$, do you mean $f$ composed with $g$, i.e. $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$?

Comment: Yes. It does use f for that. @user170231

Answer (score 1):

Some things to keep in mind:

$$\begin{align*}
(f\pm g)(x)&=f(x)\pm g(x)\\\\
(f\cdot g)&=f(x)\cdot g(x)\\\\
\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)(x)&=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}&(\text{provided that }g(x)\not=0)\\\\
(f\circ g)(x)&=f(g(x))
\end{align*}$$

You're given that $f(x)=2x^2-x-3$ and $g(x)=x+1$.

$$\begin{align*}
(f+g)(x)&=(2x^2-x-3)+(x+1)\\\\
(f-g)(x)&=(2x^2-x-3)-(x+1)\\\\
(f\cdot g)&=(2x^2-x-3)(x+1)\\\\
\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)(x)&=\frac{2x^2-x-3}{x+1}\\\\
(f\circ g)(x)&=f(g(x))\\
&=2[g(x)]^2-g(x)-3\\
&=2(x+1)^2-(x+1)-3
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Good. Applying these rules is all the OP needs to solve his problems.